# What are the steps involved in localization in Xcode?

Tags: ios, localization, swift4

I am trying to localize my application with out storyBoard in my native language urdu (Pakistan). I watch many videos and links.

I am trying follwing steps:

1. First Add the language
2. then make a new String File named Localizable.string
3. Go to View > Utilities > Show File Inspector (⌥⌘1)
4. Locate Localization section and select "Localize..."
5. Choose base language (I chose English), and click the required language and then click the localize.

After that go to "Editscheme" select the Application language, there is no option to select the urdu(Pakistan) language.
Some one says go to project.pbxpro file and make changes to it. I tried to make changes to the file but I can't succeed.

Totally confused. What can I do?

Comment: You don't need to choose the base language. The important thing is to add Urdu (Pakistan) in the Localizations section in your project settings. Have you done that?

Comment: You may wish to read the [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i).

Comment: yes i done that i add the language

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to create the Localizable file *first*, then add the language. This is because you don't have a storyboard, Xcode might not know what you want to localize when you try to add the language in the project settings.

So,

- create the Localizable.strings file first, press "Localize" and select "Base"
- Go to project settings' Localization section:

[image]

- Select the language:

[image]

- Now select Localizable.strings file to localize (in the picture I have other files as well, but you should only have Localizable.strings)

[image]

Now you should have two Localizable.strings files, one says "Base", one says "Urdu (Pakistan)". Write your localizations in the corresponding files!

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibSattar Which step are you stuck at?

Comment: i do the same things above you mentioned

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibSattar So you did everything I said? Then what do you mean by "cant localize"? Please be more specific.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibSattar Right, you need to change your simulator/phone's language to Urdu (Pakistan)

Comment: thank you lot of prayers with you...is that necessary to change the simulator/phone's language??

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibSattar Yes, that's how Apple's localisation works. If you want to change language inside the app, you can search on Google. There are a lot of libraries out there that does this. If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!